# Onion Pi No Internet

Tags: networking, internet, access-point, dns

Hey I am trying to set up and onion pi and hoping one of you can help with some issues

I successfully got the wireless access point setup and onto the internet by following this guide:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

I then followed this guide to connect the access point to Tor so all my traffic is routed through it:

https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/install-tor

The problem is after connecting to the wireless access point after installing Tor I am unable to connect to the internet. Connecting to the access point is fine but if I search for something like duckduckgo.com my browser says its unable to connect.

I tried changing trans listen address and DNS listen address to 192.168.4.1 which didn't fix anything.

Any help is appreciated as I think it would be cool to get this set up correctly.

Comment: Questions about the Onion Pi are explicitly off-topic per the site's FAQ.

Comment: Can you link me where it says that?

Comment: @user120991 https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @user120991 YOU need to edit your question to make clear this is a Raspberry Pi running Tor which has been given the name onion pi.

Comment: You should not ask where it is said that your question is off-topic. You better should take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Did you set the Pi up as authoritative dhcp? If so, then check you have a line like `option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` in dhcpcd.conf (though you May not want Google watching you)